# Adding a column and update values using SQL in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, update

I have a vector file "data.shp" containing the following fields:

```
ID, value1, AREA
```

I want to add a new column "value2" and set it as value1/AREA. Since I want to do that for many columns and files I want to use SQL.

I tried with virtual layer in QGIS with no success. I wrote in the query the following :

```
ALTER TABLE data 
ADD value2 float;
UPDATE data 
SET value2 = value1/AREA
```

Are alter and update commands working with virtual layer? Is there any other way?

Comment: AFAIK update statement is not available in virtual layers ...

Comment: @snaileater is there any way to use sql commands through QGIS?

Comment: QGIS virtual layers are using SQLite virtual table mechanism and then ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN is not supported https://sqlite.org/vtab.html. But I am not sure what is your aim. Do you want to add the new column into your shapefiles permanently?

Comment: @user30184  Yes, I want to add the new columns into the shapefile permanently.

Comment: It's not exactly SQL, but field calculator is the correct way to do this in QGIS

Comment: you can *create* a new layer (and then export as new file) using SQL in the *Virtual Layer*, with all sorts of columns, using the data *from* your shapefile, but you can't alter the shapefile itself with SQL statements. note that CRUD is not directly supported; use sth. like `SELECT col1, col2 [AS col_name] [, FUNC(col3) AS other_col_name], geometry, ... FROM <shapefile_name> [WHERE ...]; ` in the *Virtual Layer* SQL dialog (or *DB Manager*).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use just SQL, do it with ogrinfo and -sql paramater.

First command must use the GDAL OGR SQL dialect https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html

```
ogrinfo -sql "alter table my_shape add column value2 double" my_shape.shp
```

Second command must use the GDAL SQLite SQL dialect https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html

```
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "update my_shape set value2=value/(ST_Area(geometry)" my_shape.shp
```

Comment: thank you. The problem I have if I use ogrinfo is that it does not calculate the geography area but only the planimetric one (geometry). I have already made a question about this without finding any solution.

Comment: If you have GDAL that is compiled with SpatiaLite that is compiled with LWGeom you should be able to compute also geography area http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html#p8. Getting such GDAL build may be difficult. When SpatiaLite 5 is released that should be easier because LWGeom is no more needed.