# Is it possible to update column in QGIS using SQL statement?

Tags: qgis, sql

In the current LTR of QGIS - 3.14 is it possible to directly update a column using SQL?

I understand in previous questions the advice was to use OGRINFO - [Adding a column and update values using SQL in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313171/adding-a-column-and-update-values-using-sql-in-qgis)

Is there a way to run something like

```
Column_to_update = 
{Select max(End_Chainage)
from DSC_Roads
group by RoadMntnc}
```

Currently the only way I can think of doing this is to run it (as below) in DB Manager, join by a key field and then update the column. Is there a single step to do the same?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with a linestring layer (Hungarian rivers) having two attributes, "len" - the length of the feature and "NEV" - the name of the feature. Features are between two junctions, so the same name may be used several times. Using the **Field calculator** I created a virtual column with maximal length of features with the same name:

[image: field calculator expression]

Then you can see in the attribute table:

[image: result table]

I usually prefer virtual column for calculated values. The virtual columns are updated when you open the attribute table. Permanent columns must be updated manually.